# rails db:migrate fails rake aborted ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

On cloud9 IDE I installed postgresql because that is needed to deploy on Heroku, I am learning this so I am not sure, when I try to migrate a simple database table   I used this
bundle exec rake db:migrate and I get a rake aborted and a ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError:  FATAL: role "ubuntu" does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgresql comes preinstalled on Cloud9. You simply can't run bundle exec rake db:migrate though, because you have to set it up and connect to it first. Refer to the documentation here https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/setting-up-postgresql on how to set it up. Also, you dont *need* to install postgresql to be able to deploy to Heroku. You could use what rails comes with, sqlite. However, the best practice is to use the same database for development and production.

Comment: Yes I did follow that documentation, I mistook that for installing postgresql.  I am doing the Ruby on Rails tutorial book.  Where it says to change the gemfile to   gem 'pg'      '0.17.1'   gem 'rails_12factor'    '0.0.2'   So I did that ran bundle install and then rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string    This worked but the migrate failed.

Comment: did you put those gems under `group :production do`? Because those aren't needed until you actually deploy to heroku.

Comment: Do you have a `development.sqlite3` file under the db folder?

Comment: I did not have the gem under that group :production do.  I just changed it and ran a bundle install it worked.  I do have the development.sqlite3 file under the db folder.  It is empty.  thanks.

Comment: try running `rake db:create` first

Comment: Ok so I was able to do a rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string   successfully  but I still run into a problem when I run bundle exec rake db:migrate .... I get rake aborted    ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  role "ubuntu" does not exist  ugh?

Comment: yea I still get FATAL: ubuntu does not exist.  Incidentally I have same problem with another app Iam trying get started using the cloud9 IDE

Comment: do you have `gem 'sqlite3'` under `group :development, :test do`?

Comment: Yes I added that and tried again same problem:  Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"ruby-getting-started_development"}
FATAL:  role "ubuntu" does not exist

Comment: It seems like you are trying to connect to a postgresql database. What does your `configs/database.yml` look like? It should have `adapter: sqlite3` and `database: db/development.db`

Comment: confiqs/database.yml  adapter:  postgresql  database: toy_app_development  When I did the rails new toy_app command I entered database=postgresql.  This was the only way I could run rails generate scaffold Users name:string email:string

Comment: Awesome it worked.  Which leads me to think why did I start the app with postgresql.  I need this to deploy on Heroku, correct?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Heroku uses postgres, but you can use any database of your choice in development. However, the best practice is to use the same database in development as the one you will use in prodcution. For now, stick to the tutorial and use sqlite3 as its easier to set up.